# condition inside a definition, python

Tags: python, function, numpy, conditional-statements

Well I am trying to use some conditions inside a  function in Python.

My code is

```
def fitfunc(r200,c):
    x = dist[:20]*c/r200
    A = 2*delta_c_l*rho_0_2[:20]
    a1 = A*(r200/c)/(x**2-1)
    a2 = 2/(np.sqrt(1-x**2))
    a3 = np.arctanh(np.sqrt((1-x)/(1+x)))
    a4 = 2/(np.sqrt(x**2-1))
    a5 = np.arctan(np.sqrt((x-1)/(x+1)))
    if x<1:
        return a1*(1-(a2*a3))
    elif x>1:
        return a1*(1-(a4*a5))
```

Here `rho_0_2` already has some values.

dist[:20] is an array

`array([ 0.        ,  0.09317335,  0.1863467 ,  0.27952006,  0.37269341,
        0.46586676,  0.55904011,  0.65221346,  0.74538682,  0.83856017,
        0.93173352,  1.02490687,  1.11808022,  1.21125357,  1.30442693,
        1.39760028,  1.49077363,  1.58394698,  1.67712033,  1.77029369])`

When I execute `fitfunc()` I am not getting my conditions for `x>1` and `x<1` executed. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't have any values for x == 1

Comment: How are we to know? You didn't give us any *inputs* for the function. But if you are calling this function, and no exceptions are raised (which you would tell us about, right?) then those conditions are **always** executed. But if `x = 1` then neither condition is going to be True.

Comment: But if called with `fitfunc(1, 1, 1)` then most certainly `x` will be `1`.

Comment: What are `delta_c_l` and `rho_0_2`? We cannot hope to reproduce your problem if you don't give us any inputs to work with.

Comment: You still haven't given us sample input to reproduce your output (which you also didn't give). Or are you seeing an exception? If there is no exception, then the `if` and `elif` tests **are executed**, but it could still be that neither test is `True`.

Comment: Your question is getting downvoted because you have not supplied enough information to answer it.   You should share with us a script that calls this function that we can run and get the same result as you.

Comment: @MrE dist is distance. I have sorted out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `fitfunc()` is returning `None`, then `x` was `1` exactly, and neither condition is true.

Comment: say I give fitfunc(6,5,4), now the values of x will be greater than 1.

Comment: @srivatsan: sure, but then the code, *as posted* will return a result other than `None`. Or raise an exception, but that's impossible to tell without more input data.

Comment: I have sorted out the problem.